# reset memory usage of a single GPU

Tags: gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I have access to 4 GPUs(not root user). One of the GPU(no. 2) behaves weird, their is some memory blocked but the power consumption and temperature is very low(as if nothing is running on it). See details from `nvidia-smi` in the image below:
[image: nvidia-smi output]

How can I reset the GPU 2 without disturbing the processes running on the other GPUs?

PS: I am not a root user but I think I can catch hold of some root user as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

resetting  a gpu can resolve you problem somehow it could be impossible due your GPU configuration

```sh
nvidia-smi --gpu-reset -i "gpu ID"
```

for example if you have  nvlink enabled with gpus it does not go through always, and also it seems that nvidia-smi in your case is unable to find the process running over your gpu, the solution for your case is finding and killing associated process to that gpu by running following command, fill out the PID with one that are you find by fuser there

```sh
fuser -v /dev/nvidia*

kill -9 "PID"
```